# How to change the colored background of some text objects in Jellybeans color scheme in Vim?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, vim, color-scheme

I used to use gVim, but now I am switching to terminal Vim and would like to get rid of some annoying background highlighting which is being rendered under certain text. Here are some examples of what I am talking about:

[image]

[image]

The Vim color scheme I am currently using is Jellybeans, and I have located its file at `~/.vim/colors/jellybeans.vim`.

**What should I change in that color scheme file to get rid of the background highlighting around some of the text?**

Comment: Jellybeans sets colors for spell checking as of [v1.4](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2555). (although, also with background highlighting.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pieces of text on red and violet background are probably spelling
errors. The color scheme you use does not configure the highlighting
for spelling errors, so the default one is active.

There are four highlighting groups responsible for spelling errors’
appearance: `SpellBad`, `SpellCap`, `SpellRare`, `SpellLocal` (see
`:help spell-quickstart`). The default options for these groups are
defined to be something like the following:

```
:hi SpellBad term=reverse ctermbg=224 gui=undercurl guisp=Red
:hi SpellCap term=reverse ctermbg=81 gui=undercurl guisp=Blue
:hi SpellRare term=reverse ctermbg=225 gui=undercurl guisp=Magenta
:hi SpellLocal term=underline ctermbg=14 gui=undercurl guisp=DarkCyan
```

You can change the highlighting settings of these groups to your
liking, and then append the corresponding `:highlight` commands
to a custom color scheme file.

Note that it is also possible to run `:highlight` commands manually
and experience changes in appearance on the fly, to find the right
colors without reloading the whole color scheme file.