# why is vim highlighting certain text on OS X Mavericks (spf13vim)?

Tags: vim, osx-mavericks, color-scheme, spf13vim

I just installed [Steve Francia's "Ultimate Vim Distribution"](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim) on a fresh copy of OS X Mavericks, and I'm having some difficulty with getting the color scheme to work properly in Vim. The problem is that certain text is being highlighted (the background color is set)...

[image]

I've been fighting to figure this out, but I'm stuck. I don't understand where these colors for the highlighted text are coming from, or why it's different for different text. Any ideas?

p.s. I'll be happy to provide more information about my setup if it's needed.

Comment: Drop that stupid distribution and do your configuration yourself. You'd never see an unexpected behavior if you did the right thing from the start.

Comment: @romainl... what makes it stupid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell about why the colors are different, maybe the examples were taken with a different terminal?

But I *can* tell why some words are highlighted! That's very likely because you have spell-check enabled. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10963536/912144) that asks about highlighted text in vim. To remove spell-checking, simply do:

```
:set nospell
```

or put

```
set nospell
```

in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: +1 you're right about the spelling. thanks! but I still need to figure this color difference b/c it is annoying!

Comment: If you do `:colorscheme` that should tell you the color scheme that you are using. It's possible that the value has changed.